# unable to import csvwriter in my java project

Tags: java, xml, csv, export-to-csv

I want to use CSVWriter in my java project but i am unable to import it.
is there some external library which i need to download.

```
import java.io.FileWriter;

public class CreateCSV
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
   {
      String csv = "C://work//data.csv";
      CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(csv));

      //Create record
      String [] record = "4,David,Miller,Australia,30".split(",");
      //Write the record to file
      writer.writeNext(record);

      //close the writer
      writer.close();
   }
}
```

please help to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be a external library for csv. may be you can use jcsv,opencsv, commons csv etc. You have add it to classpath while compiling and running..